# Markov chain with variables

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

Let m= the number of Mercedes E550s delivered to the dealership at one time (both initially and subsequently), and let p= the probability an E550 is sold in any particular week (m = 5 and p = .3 in the previous exercise). Determine the steady-state probabilities for this chain and then the average number of weeks between vehicle orders.

```
> D
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
[2,]  0.3  0.7  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
[3,]  0.0  0.3  0.7  0.0  0.0  0.0
[4,]  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.7  0.0  0.0
[5,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.7  0.0
[6,]  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.3  0.7
```

I know I have the transition matrix right for m = 5 and p = 0.3, but I'm stuck on how to create the transition matrix and find the steady state probabilities using just variables

Comment: to find the steady state probabilities, this is the vector $\pi$ where $\pi P = \pi$. $P$ is the transition matrix.

Comment: Since $\mathbb P(X_{n+1} = 6\mid X_n=6)=1$, this is an absorbing Markov chain, so the only stationary or limiting distribution you're going to get is a point mass of one at state $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the matrix with itself until all columns converge to the same vector,  that's the steady state